# MySQL Error Code: 1265 Data truncated for column 'x' at row 1

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to load a csv file to a MySQL database.  The csv file looks as follows:

```
Property_Class,Property_Address,Property_City,Sale_Date,Sale_Price,Land_Square_Feet,Age,Rooms,Bedrooms,Basement,Central_Heating,Central_Air_Conditioning,Fireplaces,Full_Baths,Half_Baths,Sale_Year,Sale_Month
205,7121 N MASON AVE,CHICAGO,2018-11-23,367500.0,4375.0,72,6,3,Partial,Warm Air Furnace,Central A/C,0.0,6,0.0,2018,11
203,7427 N OLCOTT AVE,CHICAGO,2020-12-07,380000.0,5000.0,66,5,3,Full,Warm Air Furnace,No Central A/C,0.0,5,0.0,2020,12
205,7434 N OLEANDER AVE,CHICAGO,2018-05-01,429000.0,3750.0,65,6,3,Slab,Warm Air Furnace,Central A/C,0.0,6,1.0,2018,5
203,6754 N OCTAVIA AVE,CHICAGO,2020-06-10,288000.0,4062.0,94,7,2,Full,Warm Air Furnace,Central A/C,0.0,7,0.0,2020,6
```

When I run the following in MySQL Workbench:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'C:/ProgramData/MySQL/MySQL Server 8.0/Uploads/cook_county_sales_data.csv' 
   INTO TABLE cook_home_sales.home_sales
   FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
       OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' 
   LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n' 
   IGNORE 1 ROWS;
```

I get the following error message:

```
Error Code: 1265. Data truncated for column 'Property_Class' at row 1
```

The `Property_Class` field is defined as an `int`.  Notably, there is also a primary key named `Pkey`, which is defined as an `int not null auto-increment`.  The table definition is as follows:

```
cursor.execute("CREATE TABLE cook_home_sales.home_sales (Pkey int not null auto_increment, Property_Class int, Property_Address text, Property_City text, Sale_Date text, Sale_Price varchar(255), Land_Square_Feet int, Age int, Rooms int, Bedrooms int, Basement text, Central_Heating text, Central_Air_Conditioning text, Fireplaces int, Full_Baths int, Half_Baths int, Sale_Year int, Sale_Month int, PRIMARY KEY(Pkey))")
```

I'm on a Windows system.

Does anyone see what's causing this error?

Thanks!

**UPDATE**

I set `IGNORE 0 ROWS`:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'C:/ProgramData/MySQL/MySQL Server 8.0/Uploads/cook_county_sales_data.csv' 
   INTO TABLE cook_home_sales.home_sales
   FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
       OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' 
   LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n' 
   IGNORE 0 ROWS;
```

I set the following:

Now, I see the following error:

```
DatabaseError: 1366 (HY000): Incorrect integer value: 'Property_Class' for column 'Pkey' at row 1
```

Answer (score 0):

The table is defined as

- `Pkey int not null auto_increment`
- `Property_Class int`
- ...

You import this data

```
205,7121 N MASON A
```

separated by `','`. Thus, the second value to be assigned to the `int` field  `Property_Class` is this:

```
7121 N MASON AVE
```

Some not much like an `int`. Thus, the value gets truncated.

Comment: SteAP -- thank you.  Is the root cause of this error because I have not "told" SQL that the source csv file does not contain a column for the primary key? If yes, how do I fix that?

Comment: No, that's not related to primary key. Read the problem message. It stated that Property_Class is the problematic field.

Comment: I'm relatively new to SQL.  Should I set it to `IGNORE 0 ROWS`?  (or perhaps remove that statement altogether?)